# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.' for CustomCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I am getting error like
 `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'`

For `iOS 5.0` even if I uncheck the AutoLayout and make deployment support for All version of iOS for the customcell .

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"GroupListCell";

        GroupListCell *cell = (GroupListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib;

                if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                {
                    nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GroupListCell" owner:self options:nil];
                }
                else{
                    nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GroupListiPhoneCell" owner:self options:nil]; // sigabrt
                }
                // cell implementation code..
           }
}
```

This code is working fine with iOS6.0 but not for iOS 5.0.
what is the issue? am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the issue.

I have one textview in my cell and it has attributed text even if the Text property is define as "Plain". It is not changed in "Plain". Because changes are made in text Manually and use enter keyword to go to next line. Internally it is considered as "Attributed".

So check the text property for the TextView 2 times. :)

Answer (score 15):

Check nib file with values set in the below figure
[image]

Check `UILabel`  `UIButton` text also

[image]

Comment: yes it is already set in that way. i mentioned it in my question

Comment: Do you have any label or button in nib?

Comment: i set the text as plain for the lable

Answer (score 4):

some time `AutoLayout` may also cause problem. So take xib file - inspector pane - un tick `autolayout`.

Answer (score 1):

The code for extracting the cell might be missing in your case.Hope the below corrected code works.

```
if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib;

                if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                {
                    nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GroupListCell" owner:self options:nil];

                  cell = [nib objectAtindex:0]; 
                }
                else{
                    nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GroupListiPhoneCell" owner:self options:nil]; // sigabrt
                  cell = [nib objectAtindex:0];
                }
                // cell implementation code..
           }
```

Comment: not working it just throw the sigabrt above that so not going to the particular line that you add.

Comment: Put an exception break point and check where exactly getting the error

Comment: @Anil I just return the //sigabrt in code the point where i am getting the error.

Comment: At what point? when loading nib? did you check the nib name is correct?

Comment: yes i already check it and it is correct because it is working fine for iPhone 6.0 simulator. and yes @Anil loading the nib at that point error is occure

Answer (score 1):

For lower version of iOS 6 it can happen.

To solve this problem

Select storyboard then

In `File Inspector`->`Interface Builder Document` uncheck `Use Auto Layout`

and

In `File Inspector`->`Localization` uncheck `Base` and check `English`