# MVVMCross KittenView error Binding Cells

Tags: mvvmcross

This error is actually coming up in my own app too, but I thought I'd just refer to the identical issue which is in the **KittenView_Mac** project.

If I run the project on iPhone 6.0/6.1 Emulator, everything works fine. If I run it on 5.1, it crashes when trying to bind the custom table cells in the xib file. The error is:

`[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb4a3200`

If I run it on 4.3, I get:

`[UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c6a200`

Is there something I need to change to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I must give credit to Stuart for guiding me in the right direction with this. I had no idea what `[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]` meant - having no background in Obj-C - now I realise what it means is 'I can't find that method!'

This line in the code:

```
return (UITableViewCell)TableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier, indexPath);
```

to work with iOS 5, needs to become:

```
return (UITableViewCell)TableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
```

So that gets it to actually execute that method - but then iOS was telling me the nib file was invalid. So thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15019273/31902 I found my solution - need to make the xib file compatible with earlier versions of iOS!

Now, this seems to crash 4.3, but as per Stuart's comments, I'm happy with my app running on 98.5% of all iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross officially supports iOS 6.0 and later - which is currently over 90% of all iOS devices - http://stats.unity3d.com/mobile/index-ios.html

Most of MvvmCross does work, however, on iOS5 - which brings us to 98.5% of all iOS devices.

If you want to get support working on iOS4 and earlier, then you will need to avoid a few areas - including this `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier` which was (I guess!) introduced after iOS4.

To make this work, you'll need to code your own iOS4-compatible TableViewSource which will create new cells directly rather than relying on this `registerNib` api.

To do this, you can use your own custom `TableViewSource` inheriting from `MvxTableViewSource` - something like:

```
 public class MyTableViewSource : MvxTableViewSource
 {
    public MyTableViewSource(UITableView tableView)
        : base(tableView)
    {
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var existing = (UITableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(KittenCell.CellIdentifier);
        if (existing != null)
            return existing;

        return KittenCell.Create();
    }
 }
```